# Complete the Civil War Questline Without Picking Sides?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it somehow magically possible to complete the civil war questline without picking sides? I just completed the main dragon questline and the civil war questline is on my sights, and I think both sides can be quite obnoxious and both can't seem to see the consequences of their actions.

As far as I know I need to pick a side, but I want to know if I'm just missing something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to finish the main quest and stay neutral in Skyrim's Civil War?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38110/is-it-possible-to-finish-the-main-quest-and-stay-neutral-in-skyrims-civil-war)

Comment: No. The duplicate asks about finishing the MAIN quest line while remaining neautral. This question asks about finishing the CIVIL WAR quest line while neutral, which isn't possible. They're two independent quest lines, as the "duplicate" points out. Thus, it is not a duplicate either.

Answer (score 8):

**No**.

You're not missing anything, you can either leave the war in it's unresolved state or you resolve it on one side or the other.

An alternative could be to install a mod which makes it possible for your side to lose the war. This way your choice of side isn't guaranteed to win, removing the responsibility of picking the winner from your shoulders.

Comment: This is not true, see the duplicate link. There is a third questline.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid See my comment on the question, I meant to post that here.

Comment: My point stays the same. There is a third questline, you do not need to pick sides.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid But the OP is asking how to "Complete the Civil War Questline" - the "third" option is just a temporary truce and is NOT completing the questline. Therefor, the "third" option is not an answer to this question.

Comment: @KallumTanton It's a temporary truce? Since the speedruns go that route because you have to have finished the war and its the fastest way to do it (can't remember why, but if they do it, it must have some reason) I always tought that that was the end of that questline. No more quests in relation to the war will come afterwards. So the truce you are speaking of is lorebased, or can you break the truce later?

Comment: @Fredy31 An [earlier question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/47496/205290) indicates that the civil war questlines are available after completing the main story, indicating that either the truce was temporary or both sides are willing to break it.