# Is there a way to end the war other than joining the Stormcloaks or Imperials?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am currently level 57 and have still not taken sides with either the empire or the stormcloaks because I haven't found one of them that I really like. Is there some way to either make peace, or destroy both of them? I know that I can complete the main quest line with out taking sides, I just want to know whether there is any way that I can complete the war part of the game without taking sides

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to finish the main quest and stay neutral in Skyrim's Civil War?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38110/is-it-possible-to-finish-the-main-quest-and-stay-neutral-in-skyrims-civil-war)

Comment: @SysDragon Not quite a duplicate -- that question asks about completing the *main* quest while staying neutral; this question is specifically asking about whether the *war* can be brought to conclusion without picking a side by either convincing both of them to stop fighting or taking them both out.

Comment: Also, I don't *think* that's an option, but I can't be sure and I don't have access to the skyrim wiki here.

Comment: As the asker of that other question, I can say that these are different questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

There is no way you can complete the war part of the game without taking a side. There is no such option in-game. The war part between the factions must be completed taking one of the sides and doing the missions.

Comment: Answer is Wrong. In the speedrun they use a 3rd option, which sees both sides sit down and make peace. Pretty sure the game can't be modded to be accepted as a speedrun

Comment: That's what I like about Fallout New Vegas, there are more factions and ways to "end" the game. Instead of picking NCR or Legion, you can even go with House or fight for an Independant Vegas.

Answer (score 2):

No, at least not in an unmodded game.

The civil war plotlines have no "third option". You either side with the Stormcloaks and save Skyrim, side with the Imperials to control it for the elves, or stay out of it altogether.

If you're playing on PC, there are likely to be mods that allow this.

Comment: I couldn't find a mod that would allow this, but my search was probably not thorough enough.

Comment: Such a mod may not exist until Skyrim's modding community is a few years older, as it would require uncommon skill and dedication. Vanilla quests are a tangle of logic buried in the dialogue system that takes a lot of work to alter correctly.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Hello from the future!  [This mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/79330/) appears to do the trick (but I have not tried it so *caveat emptor*).

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually... you can! I have that problem too, I don't hate anybody in skyrim, and I honestly don't want to spill that many blood. And luckily, there is a quest for that. it's called "Season Unending". To activate this quest you must either talk to Esbern (Akaviri), Arngeir (Greybeards), or Paarthurnax about the war, and so on. Here's the link for further information http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Season_Unending

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't actually end the war; you only convince both sides to stop fighting while you deal with Alduin. Once you complete the main quest, they'll resume their war.

Comment: This quest was in fact what inspired me to ask this question in the first place. I was looking for a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Don't pick a side and while doing the quests for the grey beards, after you meet Parthanaux, you can ask the grey beards to have a meeting to stop the war.

Comment: What you speek of is brokering a truce to deal with the greater threat of the dragons.  That truce is hardly permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Nope

You will have to pick a side to carry on with the "Civil War" storyline...
However, I do have a profile where i haven't picked sides but did the "dragonborn" storyline. I got to a part where I call Tullius and Alfric (forgot the spelling) and they call a truce. I haven't really played it past that though, so I don't know.

NB: I chose the imperial side because, to me, it has a happier ending.

Comment: I chose to side with the Stormcloaks because I wanted to join the "Jedi" rather than the "Empire."

Comment: I have made the truce and the only thing I gained from that was that I got the choice to give the stormcloaks Markarth in return for giving the imperials Riften. There were probably other choices to but those were the only two I got. The truce only lasts the length of the main quest line.

Comment: @SystemFolder I assume Skyrim copied Star ars